# Variable column page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

Alright here is my dilemma. I have a bunch of divs with the same width
 (but variable heights). I want them to be displayed on the page one on top of the next UNTIL the bottom of the page, if there is space for a second column of these items on the page without scrolling then I want it to continue in the second column, third column, etc. If there is no available space left on the page then it goes off the page requiring a scrollbar to see things underneath.

This would essentially be akin to having float:top if it existed (which it sadly doesn't). Also I want this to change dynamically with the window size. If I shrink my window to one column width I want the data to go straight down one column. If I resize to two columns wide then it divides the data between the two columns.

Lastly the order of the divs MUST be preserved. I am willing to use jQuery and CSS including CSS3 to do this, anything else and I will have to look at it. I am sure that if I worked at it I could write some custom jQuery script to do this but I can't help but feel like it should be easier. I have looked at css3 columns but couldn't get them to do what I want so if they can do it the be specific as to how they do it.

Comment: Could masonry.js be what you are looking for?

Comment: I looked at that, but when I tried it it just arranged the divs similar to float:left. The only time it seems to deviate from this is when it can more efficiently use the space given to it by rearranging the order of the divs. Can you elaborate on how I might use it to stack items top to bottom left to right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of media queries? At specific break points you can apply different CSS rules, so you could change the layout of your columns.

[Have a read.](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)